# Grails select tag modification

Tags: html, grails, select

Here's the layout of my problem. I have a Location, Company, and User domain. I am trying to allow an admin to pick a new user's location with a `g:select` tag. I would like to have it produce this HTML:

```
<select name="location" id="location">
  <option value="1">Company Name - City 1</option>
  <option value="2">Company Name - City 2</option>
  <option value="3">Company Name - City 3</option>
  <option value="4">Company Name - City 4</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I can currently do this with

```
<g:select name="location" 
          from="${locations}" 
          optionKey="id" 
          optionValue="${{it.company.name + ' - ' + it.city}}"/>
```

and this saves the selection successfully, but when I go to edit the same user, it automatically jumps to a default value of `Company Name - City 1` and the admin has to re-select the desired selection. How do I modify my `g:select` to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the selected value using the `value` attribute of the `g:select`. Something along these lines:

```
<g:select name="location" 
  value="${user?.location?.id}"
  from="${locations}" 
  optionKey="id" 
  optionValue="${{it.company.name + ' - ' + it.city}}"/>
```

Comment: Ferris Bueller you're my hero. As a side note, I've been seeing the use of `?` a lot and don't know what it means. What is the difference between `${user?.location?.id}` and `${user.location.id}`?

Comment: In Groovy the question mark before a dot when accessing a property is a null safe check. Meaning, in Java if you were to try and get the value of `user.location.id` and the `location` property was null you would get an NPE (null pointer exception). However, using the question mark in Groovy avoids this.

Comment: I've been doing a bunch of `<g:if test="...">`'s to handle those. *facepalm* This is going to make my life a whole lot easier and my code a whole lot easier to read and maintain. Thank you very much!